# A book on finite state continuous time Markov chain

Tags: markov-chains, markov-process

I want to read in detail about finite state continuous time Markov chain. Can anybody suggest a book which deal this topic in detail?

Comment: Got something from the answer below?

Comment: @Did, I could not get this book, however I looked at a book by Taylor and Karlin and some lecture notes. It cleared some of my doubts. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

You might have a look at James Norris, [Markov chains](http://www.statslab.cam.ac.uk/~james/Markov/).

Comment: I just visited the link and all the topics on continuous  time seem unlinked. :(

Comment: @Undisputed007 You know what, the book exists as a physical object as well.

Comment: Thanks, i found it here [link](http://www.leg.ufpr.br/~eder/Markov/Markov%20Chains.pdf)